# Pentaho DI (Kettle) best way to select flow based on csv file header?

Tags: kettle, pentaho-spoon

I'm using Pentaho DI (kettle) and not sure what's the best way to do the following:
From a downloaded csv file, check if a column exists, and based on that select the right next step.
There are 3 possible options.

Thanks,
Isaac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not mention possible options, so I'll just provide you with a sketch showing how to check if a column exists in a file.

For this you will need a `CSV file input` step and `Metadata structure of stream` step which will read the metadata of the incoming stream.

[image: Transformation]

For a sample csv file with 3 columns named `col1`, `col2` and `col3` you get every column in a separate row with its name as a value in `Fieldname` column in **Metadata** step.

[image: Metadata results]

Then depending on your needs you could use for example `Filter Rows` or `Switch / Case` step for further processing.